# How should a character´s movement change after colliding with a wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors, collision

This character is supposed to move in a straight line in any direction. Logically, it would mantain some momemtum and redirect its movement after colliding. Here is an elastic collision, where AB is a wall and CE is the motion vector the character would have if the wall wasn´t there. And the blue vector, DF, the resulting vector after the collision.

[image]

Then, how can I get the x and y coordinates of the blue vector? Is its magnitud the same as DE?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is unclear. "*red line is the movement vector and the blue one its redirection*" What is the difference between the two? Is one the motion before and the other the motion after collision? Is the black line between A and B resembling a wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming the black line between A and B is a firm, stationary wall. Also assuming the red arrow represents the motion before collision while the blue is the motion after collision.*

In ideal (elastic) collisions with ideal (smooth) walls, only the *perpendicular part* of the motion (technically, of the momentum) changes. The parallel part remains unchanged. Vector blue should leave the wall at the same angle as vector red enters.

So, simply split vector red into its parallel and perpendicular components:

$$\vec v_\text{red}=(v_\parallel,v_\perp).$$

Vector blue is then:

$$\vec v_\text{blue}=(v_\parallel,-v_\perp).$$

This is due to Newton's 3rd law with this assumed ideal, smooth wall as well as conservation of kinetic energy in this assumed ideal, fully elastic collision (where no energy is lost as heat, permanent deformation etc.).

If you don't have the parallel and perpendicular components of vector red already, then most likely you do have the magnitude (length, size), $r$, and direction (angle to the wall), $\theta$, of vector red. From this the components are simple to find:

$$v_\parallel=r\sin(\theta)\quad \text{ and }\quad v_\perp=r\cos(\theta).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Steeven. All your assumptions are correct, and you explained this relatively well. I just have some doubts left: am understanding that the "r" is the magnitude (sorry if it´s a dumb question), then, is θ the angle between the red vector and the blue vector, or which angle exactly (again, sorry if it´s a dumb question)? And finally, the red vector that am supposed to use to get the parallel and perpendicular components... is it the whole red vector, or just the red vector from the hit.point on the wall to the very end?

Comment: Also (I ran out of characters, and sorry if I have too many doubts), I think that both the perpendicular and parallel components would be vectors by themselves... am I supposed to make an addition? Because you are placing them as if the were the independent x and y coordinates.

Comment: @Fernando No, worries. "*am understanding that the "r" is the magnitude*" Correct. "*then, is θ the angle between the red vector and the blue vector*" No, it is the impact angle of vector red. So the angle between red and black.

Comment: @Fernando "*is it the whole red vector, or just the red vector from the hit.point on the wall to the very end?*" I'm not sure what you mean. If vector red represents the motion, then you should use the whole vector. Because the magnitude of that vector would then represent speed (or momentum). I don't understand what you mean by the vector hitting the wall and then, what, having another end or something? Should I interpret this as the red vector passing through the wall? In that case I might have completely misunderstood what these vectors mean. What *exactly* does vector red represent?

Comment: @Fernando "*I think that both the perpendicular and parallel components would be vectors by themselves*" Well, sure, we could interpret them as vector components. But that wasn't my intention. Just use their sizes, their magnitudes. Meaning, just use the coordinate values that you can calculate from the equations in my last line of the answer. "* am I supposed to make an addition*" No, no addition. I'm not sure why you would think so - you only need to calculate the values of $v_\parallel$ and $v_\perp$ because then you have the blue vector's coordinates. Then you are done.

Comment: I edited the question to add a third image for clarity. Just to be safe, is the θ angle the green angle, or the yellow angle, because both are angles between the red vector and the wall. Then, just to clarify (and because your confusion is confusing me), the red vector is the whole motion assuming it doesn´t collide, from C to E. The other vector that I meant is from D to E. (Am assuming the blue vector has the same magnitude that DE). And lastly, am understanding that the result of the equations are directly the, x and y coordinates, respectively. Is this right?

Comment: @Fernando Yes, the green angle. Always go for the smaller of the two (because you are of course fight that there are always two angles to choose from). Regarding what vector fed represents, we might have to more accurately define what "the motion vector" means. Where do you have the red vector from? Is it velocity? What is the starting point where it is drawn from?

Comment: This is for a videogame, so currently am doing it like this: vector red (movement) = velocity * Time.deltaTime. (where the delta time is the time from the previous to the current frame, ideally 1/60. Say the framerate drops and there´s a second of difference: then delta time is 1 and movement = velocity). So basically, the movement is literally the way the character is going to move this exact frame (And I think it´s still velocity, but am not sure). Here is another line of code if it helps : velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime; (the velocity.y increases -9.81m/s every second).

Comment: @Fernando Alright. In physics terms your vector Red actually is a **displacement vector**. It is the total covered distance that is drawn out by the red vector. Is it correctly understood, that vector red passing through the wall corresponds to how the displacement would have been of there was no wall? If so, then vector blue is indeed, as you suggested, just as long as the part of vector red that is on the other side. Do you know the impact angle (the smaller one)? If you do, then vector blue is easy to find. ...

Comment: @Fernando... Vector blue is simply a vector directed away from the wall with *that same angle* and which is *just as long* as the part of vector red beyond the wall.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, really, but I think am doing something wrong, since the behaviour is not what you described. Here´s what am doing: first I get the displacement magnitude, then subtract the CD distance to get the magnitude of the DE. Then I move the character to the original collision point and keep the with the math. I get the impactAngle the way (I think) works = 90 - Vector2.Angle(-hitNormal, movement)  (its a built-in function that gets the angle, so am doing 90 - the angle between the negative normal of the wall and the original, whole displacement vector).

Comment: Then am getting the parallel and perpendicular numbers the way you described, using the magnitude I talked about and the impact angle. Then, finally, am defining vector blue as (parallelComponent, -perpend_Component); This is the step that I think is wrong, since it never made much sense to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and time. I finally found a solution using vector projection, but I found the solution thanks to you. Just so you know that you don´t have to answer my previous questions.

Comment: @Fernando That is awesome to hear :D Nice chatting with you. Good luck with the program.

Answer (score 0):

Physically a particle would reflect, like a snooker ball. But I think you're saying you don't want that.

You're probably looking for a *projection* – if $\mathbf{p}$ is the momentum of the character and $\mathbf{a}$ is the direction vector of the wall, then the momentum after collision would be
$$
\frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{a}}{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}}\mathbf{a}
$$

As far as the character should go, the momentum should remain the same with no forces (Newton's First Law) so in theory it'll go on forever. Again, I imagine you'll have some resistive force but it's up to you if e.g. you want the character to travel a constant distance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can´t seem to be able to post another image, but by projection do you mean that the dotted orange line should form a 90 degree angle with the slope instead of simply moving to the left? Also, is that is the case, should the blue line end right where the orange does? I will update the question to post a new image. But since this is for an indie videogame, the red line is just what is going to move this exact frame, so it won´t go forever (again, would it end right where the orange line intersects?)

Comment: Also, reflecting like a snooker ball is fine. I want wathever would happen if an object were to collide like this. (in fact, I could use both options). Can you tell me how would work something like this? Sorry for asking too much. I don´t know much of physics.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is for a video game. If this is the case you can implement it however you like or whatever works best for your game. If the character and wall were rigid bodies they would reflect. If the character is a soft body they would just collide and mush against the wall. If the character is somewhere in-between something in-between will happen that will probably depend on exact details of geometry etc.

I think it will be better to project onto the wall axis (like in your second image) rather than the y axis (like in your first image) because then the behavior won't change depending on the absolute rotation of the wall in your space but will rather only depend on the angle between the character's velocity and the wall normal.

You may be interested in checking out this video series by Pannenkoek about how collisions with walls work in Mario. Not to say you should do it that way, there are some idiosyncracies that lead to glitches, but very informational nonetheless and may spark ideas.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnU7DJXiMAQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1kbABTyeo8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRCjVLqjST4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9fUV7uA2_s

### How Rigid Body Reflection Works

Rigid body reflection works as follows. Let $v$ be the vector describing the velocity of the character/object. Let $u$ be a vector parallel to the wall. We can write

$$
\text{proj}_u(v) = \frac{v\cdot u}{u\cdot u} u
$$

$\text{proj}_u(v)$ is the [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of $u$ onto the vector $v$. The component of $v$ orthogonal to $u$ is given by $v_{\perp} = v-\text{proj}_u(v)$. The vector $v$ can then be expanded as

$$
v = \text{proj}_u(v) + v_{\perp}
$$

To reflect $v$ across the wall ($u$) we take

$$
v_{\text{ref}} = \text{proj}_u(v) - v_{\perp}
$$

That is, the component of $v$ parallel to the wall does not change, but the component perpendicular to the wall flips signs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  In your first paragraph you said that the rigidbody would reflect. How would I do that? Am not saying am going to completely ignore the other approach, but both solutions can be useful. And what is a soft body? I´ve never heard of them.

Comment: @Fernando I've added an edit explaining reflection. A rigid body is one that loses no energy to internal deformation or friction heating procesess. Think of a billiards ball. A soft body is like a ball of putty. If you throw it at a wall it smooshes and deforms and then just stops and falls. All of its kinetic energy went into deforming the object or heat.